# How do I make new/edits to nodes pass through intermediary for acceptance first?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like my users to be able to create and edit their own content. However, after they create new content, and after they edit it, I would like to have a way to accept those changes. Meanwhile, before changes are accepted, the previous version of the node will remain visible. Can this be accomplished with workbench, or is there another route I should take?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the node content type unpublished by default from [admin/structure/types/manage/article]  where "article" is the node content type...and then you can use "[views](http://drupal.org/project/views)" module to display all un published node... then you can manage the unpublished nodes and make theme published...

then 
you can use [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to make the node unpublish  after its edited by the user

Comment: how would this work to have node which is already displayed? For example, if it was published, edited, how can I be sure the contents are appropriate for the website? Or does an unpublished node type by default keep track of revisions somehow?

Comment: you can use rules module....rule module can make something like (after the user edit the node unpublish this node and send me a mail)...

Comment: Anyway to keep the original version published, while the edits are reviewed?

Comment: im not sure if rules control node revisions  or not..but can you check this pls http://drupal.org/project/revisioning

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Maestro module](http://drupal.org/project/maestro).  It is a way to implement workflows into your site.

From the project page:

> The Maestro module is a workflow engine/solution that will facilitate
>   simple and complex business process automation. The first release of
>   this module will be for Drupal v7.
>
> Maestro has a number of components that include the workflow engine
>   and the visual workflow editor. The workflow editor is used to define
>   the workflow, creating a workflow template. The workflow engine runs
>   in the backgound and executes the workflow tasks, testing the tasks
>   execution results and branch the workflow if required. The workflow
>   engine will run every x seconds and execute all tasks that are in the
>   queue which have not yet completed. Once they execute and return a
>   success status, the engine will archive them and step the workflow
>   forward. Both these components have been developed to support any
>   number of different task types. New task types can be developed and
>   added much like the Drupal CCK module can support new field types.

Answer (score 0):

> I have installed and configure the "Maestro" Module in Drupal Commons.

actually in Maestro Module every time we should Load the Workflow and it will go through step by step.
Like

1. Admin: Publishing Workflow Load
2. User1: Assigend to add new Content.
3. User2: Review Content
4. User3: Publish Content.

Here I want to Skip the Admin Step Is it possible? When user create new content type it is automatically go for review.